# Singular locus of affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, macaulay2

**Problem statement:** Find the singular locus of $V(J) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{7}$ where $J$ is the ideal

$$(A_1 D_1 - S A_2 D_2, B_1 D_1 -S B_2 D_2, A_1 D_2 + A_2 D_1, B_1 D_2 + B_2 D_1).$$

Find the irreducible components.

The singular locus is defined as the set of singular points of $V$. Usually I am given a hypersurface to calculate the singular points but in this case I have an ideal. Do I then need to solve a system of partial derivatives (equal to 0) for each polynomial generating the ideal?

Note: I am allowed to use Macaulay2, but I am not good at it at all.

**Edit:** I followed the hint(s) given in the comments by Tabes Bridges. The first step is to find the Jacobian matrix $(\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_j})$. Thus, let

$$f_1 = A_1 D_1 - SA_2 D_2 \quad \quad \quad \quad f_2 = B_1 D_1 - S B_2 D_2,$$

$$f_3 = A_1 D_2 + A_2 D_1 \quad \quad \quad \quad f_4 = B_1 D_2 + B_2 D_1.$$

Note that since I don't know how the coordinates are given (i.e. in which order s.t. $f_i \in k[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_7]$) I chose $X_1 = A_1, X_2 = A_2, X_3 = B_1, X_4 = B_2, X_5 = D_1, X_6 = D_2, X_7 = S$. Then the Jacobian matrix becomes

$$\begin{pmatrix}
D_1 & -S D_2 & 0 & 0 & A_1 & -S A_2 & -A_2 D_2 \\
0 & 0 & D_1 & -S D_2 & B_1 & -S B_2 & -B_2 D_2 \\
D_2 & D_1 & 0 & 0 & A_2 & A_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & D_2 & D_1 & B_2 & B_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The next step would be to find the vanishing minors. If I recall correctly, then minors are the determinants of submatrices. The issue here is that there seem to be far too many submatrices to consider doing by hand.

Comment: You need to look at the Jacobian matrix $(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)$. The singular locus is precisely where it drops rank, which you can express in terms of vanishing of minors.

Comment: @TabesBridges But in this case, what is $f$? I have an ideal generated by four polynomials.

Comment: I wrote $f_i$, not $f$. You will have one row in the matrix for each polynomial.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked the index. So I followed your hint(s) and calculated the Jacobian matrix (see edit to post). There are some issues now that I encountered. 1. I had to make a choice for labelling the coordinates $X_j$ and I've done this according to the edit. Does the choice matter or could I just relabel them? 2. Now, the next step is to compute the determinants of submatrices. This seems like a lot of computations to do by hand since I suppose there are many submatrices. Is there some technique here to find all vanishing minors and sidestep many computations? I am also allowed to

Comment: use a computer for computation but I don't know how to do this in Macaulay2 for instance.

Comment: The choice of coordinates doesn't matter since that just alters the matrix by interchanging columns, which does not change the rank. I don't think you can get out of doing that rather cumbersome computation, but I will be no help for Macaulay2. I imagine if you google "macaulay2 rank matrix" or something like that you will find some helpful ideas.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and figure out how to carry out the computations on a computer.